# Opencv ffmpeg: Video capture ("Filename.avi") crashes on a non development machine - MAC 10.8.2

Tags: qt, opencv, deployment, ffmpeg, video-capture

I was trying to deploy a simple Qt Opencv Application, the following is the code:

Qt: .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = opencvVideoTest
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH = -I/usr/local/include

LIBS += -lm -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc
```

Mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    cv::Mat img;

   cv::VideoCapture cap("BMWM5.avi");

   if(cap.isOpened()){

   for(;;){
       cap.read(img);
       cv::resize(img,img,cv::Size(604,480));
       cv::imshow("Opencv", img);
       cv::waitKey(33);
   }
   }
   else{

   }


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

The above snippet works fine on the development machine, which by the has Opencv 2.4.3, ffmpeg 1.1.2 & Qt 5.0.1. This what happens when I try to deploy, running the otool before using macdeployqt and the output:

```
>   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current
 version 169.3.0)   /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_core.2.4.3.dylib
 (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.3)
 >  /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.3.dylib
 (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.3)
>   /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_imgproc.2.4.3.dylib
   (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.3)
>   /usr/local/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
  (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.1)
>   /usr/local/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui
  (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.1)
>   /usr/local/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore
  (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.1)
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
  (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL
  (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
>   /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current
  version 56.0.0)
```

otool after macdeployqt output:

> ```
> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
>     @executable_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_core.2.4.3.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.3)
>   @executable_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_highgui.2.4.3.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.3)
>   @executable_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_imgproc.2.4.3.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.3)
>   @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
> ```
>
> (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.1)
>         @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.1)
>         @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.1)
>         /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
>         /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
>         /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 56.0.0)

But after deploying it, when I try and run the app on the user's machine it crashes, no error reported either, the exact samething used to happen in Windows but when I copied the opencv_ffmpeg.dll into the exe folder it worked fine. I tried to use the same logic here and failed, then I manually addded each lib files of all the ffmpeg and its dependency into the project folder and still failed. Any other solution, please help? I'm a newbie to mac dpeloyment. Am i missing or overlooked something?